# Why isn't my program parsing the entirety of my .csv file?

Tags: java, file, csv, bufferedreader

I'm working on a damage calculator for Pokemon and a part of that is creating a database of all Pokemon and their relevant data, such as types, abilities, and stats. If you would like to see the CSV for yourself, here's a link to Google Sheets: [pokemon csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uHj-vvrv_uIFDYMef9TJGu6pPyKXTq_mj57EZ5z0LeU/edit?usp=sharing). For the code that parses it, I use a BufferedReader to go line by line and split the lines up to assign the appropriate values:

```java
Path filePath = Paths.get("src//pokemon.csv");
        String line = "";

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)){
            reader.readLine();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String [] pokemonData = line.split(",");

                for(String s: pokemonData) {
                    System.out.print(s + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");

                Pokemon dummy = new Pokemon();
                dummy.setDexnum(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[0]));
                dummy.setRegion(pokemonData[1]);
                dummy.setName(pokemonData[2]);
                for (Type t: types) {
                    if (t.name.equals(pokemonData[3])) {
                        dummy.setType1(t);
                    }
                }
                for (Type t: types) {
                    if (t.name.equals(pokemonData[4])) {
                        dummy.setType2(t);
                    }
                }
                dummy.setAbility1(pokemonData[5]);
                dummy.setAbility2(pokemonData[6]);
                dummy.setHidden_ability(pokemonData[7]);
                dummy.setBaseHp(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[8]));
                dummy.setBaseAttack(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[9]));
                dummy.setBaseDefense(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[10]));
                dummy.setBaseSpecialAttack(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[11]));
                dummy.setBaseSpecialDefense(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[12]));
                dummy.setBaseSpeed(Integer.parseInt(pokemonData[13]));

                dummy.setFullyEvolved(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[15]));
                dummy.setCanMegaEvolve(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[16]));
                dummy.setMegaEvolution(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[17]));
                dummy.setLegendary(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[18]));
                dummy.setMythical(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[19]));
                dummy.setUltraBeast(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[20]));
                dummy.setBabyPokemon(Boolean.parseBoolean(pokemonData[21]));

                pokemon.add(dummy);

            }
        }

        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print("no");
        }
```

All of this works fine and well, Pokemon objects are being created and the data lines up perfectly. However for some reason, the program just stops parsing the csv before reaching the end. Specifically, it stops at line 757. Any help is appreciated

Comment: suggest you use a csv reader like opencsv

Comment: Try to provide a minimal full working class that reproduces the problem and the full error stack trace.

Comment: Is it printing no as in it's failing? What happens at the end?

Comment: How do you know where it is stopping?

Comment: There's a Google sheets Java library, by the way

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Comment: `catch(IOException e) {System.out.print("no");}`  Change those lines to print the exception stacktrace.  There is a good chance that the information you are currently throwing away there will well you what the problem is.

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be anything wrong with your program at a glance. How many lines are there in total? Or put another way, how many lines is it skipping? Most importantly, as @StephenC, print the stack trace, and if it doesn’t explain the reason, paste it into the question, formatted as code for readability. Also tell us which iine of your program it refers to (since counting lines in a program posted on Stack Overflow is shaky at best).

Comment: You have **missing data** on row 780 of the spreadsheet, where your ID column is 658. Columns J-N inclusive have no values. Is this sheet you linked being modified, changing? If so, perhaps your problem is missing data, and the line has been moving around.

Comment: @StephenC ok so I changed that line and I'm getting a MalformedInputException.

Comment: @OleV.V. there are 1057 lines in total and its not skipping any of them, its just stopping at line 757

Answer (score 2):

## Missing data

In the file you linked, downloaded from Google Docs as a CSV file, I find missing data in row 780 where ID column is 658. Columns J-N inclusive have **no values where an integer is expected**.

Otherwise the file can be successfully read as CSV, if we skip that bad row. All your `String`, `Integer`, and `Boolean` types can be read and parsed.

Here is example code using [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to perform the chore of opening the CSV file, and parsing each row with its column values.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PokemonImporter
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        PokemonImporter app = new PokemonImporter();
        List < Pokemon > pokemons = app.importThem();
    }

    public List < Pokemon > importThem ( )

    {
        List < Pokemon > pokemons = new ArrayList <>( 1_000 );
        Reader in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new FileReader( "/Users/basilbourque/pokemon.csv" );
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Iterable < CSVRecord > records = null;
        try
        {
            records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( in );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for ( CSVRecord record : records )
        {
            Integer id = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "" ) );
            if ( id.intValue() != 658 )
            {
                String region = record.get( "Region" );
                String name = record.get( "Name" );
                String type1 = record.get( "Type 1" );
                String type2 = record.get( "Type 2" );
                String ability1 = record.get( "Ability 1" );
                String ability2 = record.get( "Ability 2" );
                String hiddenAbility = record.get( "Hidden Ability" );
                Integer hp = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "HP" ) );
                Integer attack = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Attack" ) );
                Integer defense = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Defense" ) );
                Integer spAtk = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Sp. Atk" ) );
                Integer spDef = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Sp. Def" ) );
                Integer speed = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Speed" ) );
                Integer total = Integer.valueOf( record.get( "Total" ) );
                Boolean fullyEvolved = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Fully Evolved" ) );
                Boolean canMegaEvolve = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Can Mega Evolve" ) );
                Boolean megaEvolution = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Mega Evolution" ) );
                Boolean legendary = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Legendary" ) );
                Boolean mythical = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Mythical" ) );
                Boolean ultraBeast = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Ultra Beast" ) );
                Boolean babyPokemon = Boolean.valueOf( record.get( "Baby Pokemon" ) );

                System.out.println( " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " );
                System.out.println( "id = " + id );
                System.out.println( "region = " + region );
                System.out.println( "name = " + name );
                System.out.println( "type1 = " + type1 );
                System.out.println( "type2 = " + type2 );
                System.out.println( "ability1 = " + ability1 );
                System.out.println( "ability2 = " + ability2 );
                System.out.println( "hiddenAbility = " + hiddenAbility );
                System.out.println( "hp = " + hp );
                System.out.println( "attack = " + attack );
                System.out.println( "defense = " + defense );
                System.out.println( "spAtk = " + spAtk );
                System.out.println( "spDef = " + spDef );
                System.out.println( "speed = " + speed );
                System.out.println( "total = " + total );
                System.out.println( "fullyEvolved = " + fullyEvolved );
                System.out.println( "canMegaEvolve = " + canMegaEvolve );
                System.out.println( "megaEvolution = " + megaEvolution );
                System.out.println( "legendary = " + legendary );
                System.out.println( "mythical = " + mythical );
                System.out.println( "ultraBeast = " + ultraBeast );
                System.out.println( "babyPokemon = " + babyPokemon );
            }
        }
        return pokemons;
    }
}
```